# Edge isn't checking if HTML document has been changed

Tags: caching, web, html, microsoft-edge

I got the problem that Edge isn't checking if an html document has changed. 
Firefox and Chrome do check this. When I update an html document, the page is correctly shown in Firefox and Chrome, but Edge does still show the old page.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F5 should refresh your browser cache and reload the page.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache . There's no Edge browser mentioned here, but the same principle should work.

Comment: Did you find a solution?